# emulator in Android studio,pls help_me

Tags: android, emulation

//this is problem

"C:\Android SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Srdjan -netspeed full -netdelay none

Note: The environment variable $ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set, and the emulator uses that variable to locate AVDs.
This may result in the emulator failing to start if it cannot find the AVDs in the folder pointed to by the
given environment variable.
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=C:\Android SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and so I did everything I could possibly find online, and nothing worked. But finally Android studio and emulator loaded successfully.. :)

****Just go to your machine's BIOS setting and enable the Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x).****

After that I went to the Intel website, and I downloaded the HAXM installer that they provide (instead of using the one downloaded through Android Studio).

It works.. :)

Answer (score 0):

it occurred when you not install HAX or use X86 or X64 system images on AMD cpu
you have to install armeabi system images from sdk manager 
a better solution is that use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) emulator

Answer (score -1):

You might need to install some packages with the Package Manager.

Try these instructions?
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Comment: Is any other  solution,becouse my laptop do not support VT?